# Why does PowerShell not seem to honour the $env:path variable?

Tags: git, powershell, github, path

I installed GitHub and Git, and want to add Git to the PowerShell path. I added it to the system path, it works in cmd.exe, and shows the correct path when I print $env:path, yet PowerShell still doesn't recognize git.

I tried to restart, thinking it was maybe behind or something, but that didn't fix the problem.

If I navigate to the path git is in (by actually copying it from the output of $env:path, to make sure it's not a typo), and run ./git it works just fine.

```
PS C:\> $env:path 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\JHdJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Users\JHdJ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\JHdJ\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\JHdJ\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.5\resources\app\git\cmd"

                                                                                              #"# (dummy comment to fix syntax highlighting)

PS C:\> git
git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


PS C:\Users\JHdJ\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.5\resources\app\git\cmd> ./git
```

As said, latter works fine.

Also, in cmd.exe, running just `git` works fine.

I expect PowerShell to recognize `git` as a command, since `$env:Path` points to the dir of `git.exe`.

Comment: If your path is set up correctly, then you should only need to type `git` at the console. If you are going to qualify the command with a path, then you need to complete the path and include the extension.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I suggest only closing questions for the stated reason that are due to _one-off, incidental_ typos, which makes such questions unlikely to be of interest _to others_.
By contrast, here we're dealing with a case where a _misconfiguration_ causes subtle symptoms that (a) others may plausibly run into and (b) are worth explaining.
While my answer hopefully explains the problem and offers an effective solution, I think leaving the question closed is (a) a distraction that can lead users to think that there's nothing of interest here and (b) prevents additional answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your `PATH` environment variable (`$env:PATH`) is misconfigured**:

It contains an extraneous, unpaired `"` *as part of its value*:

```bash
# Your $env:Path value - note the unexpected, unpaired " at the end.
...;C:\Users\JHdJ\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.5\resources\app\git\cmd"
```

`cmd.exe` happens to *ignore* the extraneous `"`, but PowerShell does not, so your `C:\Users\JHdJ\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.6.5\resources\app\git\cmd` directory is effectively *not* part of `$env:PATH` from PowerShell's perspective, which explains your symptom.

The solution is to **fix the `$env:PATH` value**:

- *Ad hoc*, for the *current session* only:

  ```bash
    $env:Path = $env:Path -replace '"'  # remove embedded " chars.
  ```
- *Persistently*, for *future sessions*:

  ```bash
    $currUserPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User')
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $currUserPath -replace '"', 'User')
  ```

  - Note that `$env:PATH` is a *composite* value from two distinct registry locations: a *machine-wide* one and a *user-specific* one, and they should be updated *separately*. In your case, given that the dir. in question is *user-specific*, it is the user-specific definition that needs updating, as shown above.

Note that updating the persistent value doesn't automatically refresh the value in the *current* session, so to have it take effect there you must run the *ad hoc* command as well.